# single and double quotes in sql insert

Tags: mysql, sql, double, quotes

I had an issue come up when working with mySQL. I have a table of parts with part numbers and descriptions. I am trying to insert over a thousand parts and need to get the formatting to work for every insert. For some parts the description (text type) will be something like:

TUBE 1/2" X .049" UNANODIZED 6061 T6 12'

I tried numerous combinations of quotes but because it uses single and double quotes it's a real pain to insert as text. How can I do this so that it will work for all inserts, even those without any special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the symbol:  'TUBE 1/2\" X .049\" UNANODIZED'

I hope this helps.

Comment: That works but is there a way to do so without having to escape the character? With over a thousand lines I'd have to search every line to check if it has quotes to escape. This is impractical because every line has quotes in it but not all of them need to be escaped.

Comment: Is there any automatic way to add the escaping?  Like a replace function?  Or bring the text into a text editor and do a global search and replace?  It sounds like you have a difficult problem.

Comment: You can have a look at this [Inline Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)  Might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you use a single or double quote , use the backslash character to escape it 
TUBE 1/2\" X .049\" UNANODIZED 6061 T6 12\'